# how to debug Async callout failures

Tags: apex, rest-api, callout, unmanaged-package

we have an unmanaged package that makes an API call out to eternal system.This callout triggers based on user actions like when user creates an opportunity; it runs asynchronously as a logged in user. The issue we are having is, occasionally for random users this async callout is failing due to the apex unhandled exception thrown by apex class which is part of unmanaged package. Not able to replicate this issue in any of our environments in order to debug. how to setup logs to trace those failed transactions.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new object and create a record through a `try/catch`.  This is also good if you don't want to hard stop someone but still need to know if there is an issue.  This works for other things besides Async calls..

```
public with sharing class BusinessException extends Exception
{
    public static void recordError(String fileName, String methodName, String errorMessage)
    {
        Exception__c newException = createError(fileName, methodName, errorMessage);
        insertError(newException);          
    }

    private static Exception__c createError(String fileName, String methodName, String errorMessage)
    {
        Exception__c result = new Exception__c();
        result.FileName__c = fileName;
        result.MethodName__c = methodName;
        result.SystemError__c = errorMessage;

        return result;
    }

private static void insertError(Exception__c oopsey)
{
        try
        {
            insert oopsey;
        }
        catch(DMLException dmlError)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

And then where ever you suspect/probable failure you would wrap

```
try
{     
   //something      
}
catch(QueryException error)
{
    BusinessException.recordError('File_Name', 'Method Name', error);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know which users of the unmanaged package are likely to cause the error and roughly when you could have them enable the [debug log via a TraceFlag](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_add_users_debug_log.htm&type=0). Or assuming you have admin access to the org in question, you could do so on their behalf and then collect the resulting log.

---

You could also check [Who receives Apex exception mails?](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000170712&type=1). Since it is unmanaged code in the clients org you might be able to have your email added to the list of recipients. Or have the person that does get the emails forward the applicable ones onto you.

See [ApexEmailNotification](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_apexemailnotification.htm) from the ToolingAPI.

Comment: there are more than 150 users using that unmanaged package, this issue is  happening once in a while and to random users.